# Cross Resolution Applications in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, user-interface

We are developing a small in-house application that will run on monitor having multi resolutions. Now we want that the application should adjust itself and remain consistent over all monitors.

I came from a Java background too where we used different layouts to accomplish the task. I experimented in .NET with different layouts like UniGrid (which provide the consistency but very restrictive), Grid, etc. but failed in the required task.

What are some possible layout model or some other solution?

**I think if we can specify percentage width or height as we do in CSS/HTML then we can adopt this cross-resolution policy. I found Infergistics have such controls, but can this can be achieved via default controls?**

P.S.: I am actually trying in WPF (preferably WPF native application).

Comment: Winforms, WPF, Webforms?

Answer (score 3):

The layout controls in [WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754130.aspx) are vastly superior to those found in Windows Forms. It also features true resolution independent display using [Fixed Documents](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748388.aspx), so the look is consistent even if the monitor DPI changes. This is something that no other Windows drawing API supports properly as far as I'm aware.

Comment: But DocumentViewer which is used to create fixed documents does not support the Child Controls within it. While our application will have them, i mean its not about showing the documents on it.

Answer (score 2):

It would completely depend on the content / context of your application, but the .NET Form designer provides you with some useful tools while designing your UI.

Most controls have an **`Anchor`** property that allows you specify that a control should stay anchored the specified distance from the top/left/bottom/right of the form during resizing.

Likewise the form itself exposes **`Resize`** and **`SizeChanged`** events that you can use to customise the UI when the form is resized.

There's some information here as well regarding layouts, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms951306.aspx.